# Why are these two matrices not the same height

Tags: amsmath, matrices, ctex

code 1 with `ctex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ctex}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
   A= \begin{bmatrix}
    x
    \end{bmatrix}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

code 2 with out `ctex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    B=\begin{bmatrix}
    x
    \end{bmatrix}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: code 1]
[image: code 2]

Matrice B is shorter than A, why? How to make A same as B? I used `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{}`, but it's not perfect.

Comment: `ctex` package changes line spread, and the height of each row in a matrix is exactly the height of a single line. Package `zhlineskip` provides a way to restore line spread for math envs.

Comment: If you can read Chinese, this answer from zhihu.com gives some detailed example: https://www.zhihu.com/question/521756043/answer/2388033111.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `ctex` you have `\baselinestretch` set to 1.3, so you want to countermand it with the reciprocal for `\arraystretch`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ctex}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.76923} % 1/1.3

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
 A = \begin{bmatrix}
     x
     \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Additionally, it may also be useful to execute `\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}` in the preamble, to restore a semblance of symmetric spacing around displayed math material. Of course, this isn't directly related to the OP's question, but such an adjustment may still be desirable (as long as there is displayed math material, of course).